# What is the meaning of "is of"?

Tags: verbs, adverbs

For example:

> It is of no great bulk.

> It is of no use whatever.

> This book is of elegant format.

and so on.

I don't understand why we don't use 'is' but 'is + preposition'? especially 'is of'

And what is difference between them?

Comment: You say "format of sth", "usage of sth", etc. So you also need that "of" when you reshape your sentences. Do you think "This book is elegant format" could make any sense?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A preposition phrase headed by *of* is a common way of attributing a quality to a noun, either as a modifier or as a predicate:

> a man *of discretion* = a man who ‘possesses’ discretion, “a discreet man”.
>
> This approach is *of value*. = This approach ‘possesses’ value, “it is valuable”.

This construction pushes the attributed quality to the end of the phrase or clause, the emphatic position where ‘new information’ usually appears.

The construction is particularly useful with a modified oblique—that is, *of ADJ NOUN*—where the alternative *ADV + ADJ* would be awkward:

> This is a problem of challenging difficulty  *vs* This is a <sup>?</sup>challengingly difficult problem.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/of), the phrase **is of** means

> Possess intrinsically; give rise to.

Bulk and usefulness are characteristics of something: it possesses those characteristic intrinsically, so you should say

> It **is of** no great bulk
>   It **is of** no use whatsoever.

Similarly, something may **give rise to** interest, so you might say

> It **is of** no interest to me.

Comment: Then "is of" is something like "have"?

Comment: @bowstring: the first meaning might be replaced by **have**, but not the second.