# Does rewriting a sentence to remove "is of" reverse its meaning?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, prepositional-phrases

this [post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/137867/103381) gives a nice explanation about "is of"

> A preposition phrase headed by of is a common way of attributing a quality to a noun, either as a modifier or as a predicate

and gives this example

> This approach is of value. = This approach ‘possesses’ value, “it is valuable”.

follow this pattern

I am trying to understand this [sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorption_(acoustics))

> Acoustic absorption is of particular interest in soundproofing.

and got this

Acoustic absorption **possesses** particular interest in soundproofing.

which seems to be in a opposite order.

It is more reasonable to say soundproofing **possesses** interest in acoustic absorption.

what am I missing?

Comment: You're  missing the party who has the interest. That's probably because that party isn't mentioned explicitly in the original sentence. The interested party is anyone dealing with soundproofing. So you could say, "Anyone dealing with soundproofing will have a particular interest in acoustic absorption." *Possess* isn't a natural expression with *interest*.

Comment: @user105719 What does "party" mean here?

Comment: Sorry, that must have been misleading. In this context, "party" just means a person relevant to the discussion.

Comment: See [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/296142/the-little-money-that-you-have-given-me-is-of-great-value-to-me-here-what-do/296144#296144) for some other examples of this use of "of".

Answer (score 1):

In this situation, by "possesses" he meant "has that quality".  It refers to something internal to the object, rather than an external type of possession of something other than itself.

"Katie possesses the violin." No.
"Katie possesses talent."  Yes.

The quality under discussion here is "being interesting".  The "interesting acoustic absorption."

The entire sentence may be rewritten:

> Acoustic absorption is particularly interesting when discussing the topic of soundproofing.

Answer (score 1):

**Idiomatic usage**:

**to be of value**, of great value, of little value
**to be of interest**, of some interest, of no interest, of great interest, etc.

and to be of interest or value implies TO someone.

You can put adjectives in front of value and interest.

So, this: Acoustic absorption is of particular interest [to me or DIYers or builders] in soundproofing.

Here, you cannot use possess. As *possesses interest* for me is very stilted here. So is "possess value" here. An object may possess value, but one wouldn't say soundproofing possesses value.

Possess is transitive: **He possesses** many books on that subject.

You can explain it by saying this *approach possesses value* but  it doesn't sound like good writing.

And, finally, only a person can possess an interest in something.