# "The little money that you have given me is of great value to me." Here, what does 'of' mean?

Tags: prepositions

> The little money that you have given me is **of** great value to me.

Here, what does **of** mean and which part of speech **of** is?

Will there be any problem if I omit **OF**?

Answer (score 4):

This is a very specific use of "of" to connect an item with an attribute of that item. Other examples:

- This book may be **of** interest to you. (This book may interest you.)
- He said nothing **of** any importance. (What he said was not important at all.)
- She is a girl **of** great intelligence. (A somewhat flowery way of saying: she is very intelligent.)

Omitting "of" will make it ungrammatical, but you could instead say that something *has* great value to someone.

Comment: Thank you so much!❤️