# Can we use double possessive after the 'be'-verb?

Tags: grammar, possessives

Possessive determiners are used to modify a following noun : **Your** book, **John's** book. ('Your' / 'John's' : Possessive determiner).

This book is **yours**.
(Here, *'yours'* ----> a possessive pronoun.)

This book is **John's**.
(Here, *'John's'* -----> a possessive noun)

I know the double possessive follows a noun. But can we use double possessive after the 'be'-verbs?

> (1) This book is **of yours** (instead of, "This is a book **of yours**. )
>
> (2) This book is **of John's** (instead of "This is a book**of John's**.)

Comment: I guess that's a rearrangement of "this is John's book".

Comment: *Yours* is a possessive pronoun, and *John's* is a possessive noun.

Comment: Your question doesn't deserve the negativity it got. For instance, this is perfectly valid: *This book is **one** of yours*. This is also fine: *This is a book of words.* So, you could easily wonder why *this book is of yours* could not also be used. I wouldn't even say that *is of yours* is flat-out syntactically incorrect. But it's definitely unusual. The meaning is clear (so you wouldn't be misunderstood), but it's at least strange enough to be poetic rather than something you *should* write. (Sort of like Yoda's speech patterns in *Star Wars*.)

Comment: I would provide some kind of actual helpful answer for you. Unfortunately, I can't think of a good way of framing it.

Comment: "This is a book of yours" even that sounds a bit childish or off, but understandable.  "This book is of yours" sounds very strange and on the edge of not being understandable.  2. "This book is of John's" - this construction wants a noun to follow.  John's collection, John's making, John's doings, John's adventures, etc.  Where we are changing "of" here into "about" or "from".  "This is John's book." is best.

Comment: "This a book of yours" means "This is one of those books that you have". It's double possessive. It's absolutely correct, IMHO. But I  don't know whether "This book is of yours" is correct or not.

Comment: A very basic answer: "This book is of yours" is definitely not correct.  (The sentence is jumbled. English depends on word ordering, and you can't flip words around. )

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "is of" is a preposition phrase which has the meaning "to possess intrinsically; give rise to." The words can appear together (This book *is of* high quality) or separated by the item being referred to (This *is* a book *of* high quality)

You are using the word 'of' in this case as a function word to indicate belonging or a possessive relationship.

Thus, using it with the second possessive (yours or John's) is redundant, and creates a conflict with the commonly understood meaning of "is of," which basically makes the sentence incomprehensible, even though we can probably glean the intention of the writer.

[Of: definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/of)

[ELL: What is the meaning of "Is of?"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/137863/what-is-meaning-of-is-of)